# HttpTaskAsyncHandler does not write response on remote server

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, request, ashx

I'm doing async request to .ashx handler which works no problem locally, but when I publish the stuff to the server it doesn't write response to my client website(other synchronous requests also work no problem). I tried many things but to no avail. Here is my handler code:

```
public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var result = await SomeService.DoSomethingAsync(context.Request["id"]);

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    ApplicationLogging.Log(LogType.Info, 
      $"the result has keys:  {string.Join(", ",result.Keys)}");

    context.Response.Write(result);
    context.Response.End();
}
```

When I check the logs, the results are exactly what i expect but the response doesn't get returned to my client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but deleting

```
    context.Response.End();
```

fixed my response